# Traveling to Germany with Cyprus passport and I'm 15 years old

Tags: air-travel, germany, turkey, minors, cyprus

Hi everyone I live in northern Cyprus (it isn't important btw). I'm 15 years old and I have a Republic of Cyprus (not Northern) passport with EU (European Union) ID card.

I just booked a flight for Germany (Stuttgart) from Turkey (Istanbul). The people who work in check-in (Türk Hava Yolları/Turkish Airlines - TK) didn't tell me about problems while leaving Turkey and entering Germany as well.

I just want to be sure about any problems while leaving Turkey and entering Germany.

Will they stop me because of my age and my passport? (Turkey doesn't recognise Republic of Cyprus).

Comment: We also do not send responses directly to email. We post them on the site so that everyone can benefit from them. You can join our community (you posted as a guest) and then sign up for email notifications, to be notified of any answers to your question.

Comment: How do you plan to get from Cyprus to Turkey? https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/travel-documents-minors/cyprus/index_en.htm

Comment: @Traveller It sounds like she is already in Turkey.

Comment: Perhaps, but it's not clear. @Amylee Are you now in Turkey?

Comment: What document did you enter Turkey with? I assume you have some travel document they recognise?

Answer (score 6):

You can enter Germany (or any EU state) with just your Cyprus national ID card; a passport is not strictly required but it is good to travel with it in case you intend to travel to some other countries later.

It's recommended that you also [carry a letter of consent](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/travel-documents-minors/germany/index_en.htm) signed by your parent(s) or guardian(s):

> In addition to their own valid travel document (passport or ID card), although not obligatory by law, all minors entering or leaving Germany are advised to carry a declaration of consent (where possible in the languages of both the home country and the destination country) signed by the parents who have custody over them. The declaration should show:
>
> - that the minor has permission to travel alone,
> - the contact details of the parents with custody,
> - the route the minor will take and
> - the contact details of any accompanying adults.